# How to extract prime numbers from a fibonacci series in C program?

Tags: c, primes, fibonacci

My University exam had a question on generating the FIB series and extracting the PRIME numbers from the result. I wrote the following code and I get the correct result. However, I am sure my code is not clean.. Can someone help me with writing a new code or edit mine and make it clean?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0, n, i, position = 2, primeNumber[10], init = 2, count = 0;
    printf("Input N= ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Fibonacci List: %d %d ", t1, t2);
    nextTerm = t1 + t2;

    while (nextTerm <= n)
    {
        printf("%d ", nextTerm);
        primeNumber[position] = nextTerm;
        position++;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = nextTerm;
        nextTerm = t1 + t2;
    }

    printf("\nPrime numbers are ");
    position = 3;
    i = 1;
    init = 0;

    for (init = 1; init <= 7; init++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= primeNumber[position]; i++)
        {
            if (primeNumber[position] % i == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 2)
        {
            printf("%d ", primeNumber[position]);
        }
        count = 0;
        position++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your indentation style could be a little more consistent :-)

Comment: These point could be improved: 1: concistent indenting. 2: not cramming many variable declarations into one line. 3: not cramming all your code into main, but use functions. 4: checking input range to prevent out of bounds access of primeNumber.

Comment: There are 51 known Fibonacci primes. (You can just hardcode them all). However your array has only 10 elements. You actually do not need the array because you only calculate one element at a time, print it, and never go back to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your program doesn't run for me.  It prints the fibonacci list and then aborts.  Other issues:

- I don't understand where `7` comes from in `init <= 7` The code initializes `init = 2`, then does `init = 0` and finally does `init = 1` just before using it!
- Your prime detection logic does more work than necessary -- it tests all the divisors, but the test is over once the first divisor is found, no need to test the rest.  You also fail to limit the divisor to the square root, you end up testing all numbers less than the target.
- the `primeNumber[]` array is really filled with fibonacci numbers, not prime numbers, so the name is misleading.  It lacks index checking, and as noted in the comments, not strictly necessary.

Here's an alternate, simplified approach to the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned n, f1 = 0, f2 = 1;
    printf("Input N = ");
    scanf("%u", &n);

    printf("Fibonacci List: %d %d ", f1, f2);

    for (unsigned f3 = f1 + f2; f3 <= n; f3 = f1 + f2)
    {
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;

        bool is_prime = true; // assume it's prime until proven otherwise

        for (unsigned divisor = 2; divisor * divisor <= f3; divisor++)
        {
            if (f3 % divisor == 0)
            {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (f3 > 1 && is_prime)
        {
            printf("[%d] ", f3);
        } else {
            printf("%d ", f3);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% ./a.out
Input N = 10000
Fibonacci List: 0 1 1 [2] [3] [5] 8 [13] 21 34 55 [89] 144 [233] 377 610 987 [1597] 2584 4181 6765 
%
```

Where there is no array so it outputs fibonacci numbers and primes in one pass, with the primes in the sequence denoted with brackets.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and for rewriting the program in a proper way.